# How to get system time with higher precision?

Tags: haskell

In Erlang I can get system time this way:

```
  :os.system_time
  1583756142069346000
```

In Haskell the `time` package returns numbers that aren't similar the one of Erlang:

```
  a1 <- getSystemTime
  print $ systemSeconds a1
  print $ systemNanoseconds a1
```

I get these:

```
1583756121
121757000
```

The length is smaller: 19 vs 10. How can I get a time in the same format?

Answer (score 5):

You can combine the two fields yourself; `systemNanoseconds` returns the number of nanoseconds in the current second, rather than the time itself *in* nanoseconds. Compare:

```
1583756142 069346000  -- Erlang time, split into two fields
1583756121 121757000  -- Haskell values concatenated
```

It's not as straightforward as it could be, since `systemSeconds` and `systemNanoseconds` have different return types.

```
getErlangSystemTime = do
    a1 <- getSystemTime
    let sec = systemSeconds a1
        nsec = systemNanoseconds a1
    return $ sec * 10^9 + fromIntegral nsec
```

I'm not aware of a pre-existing function that returns the time as a number of nanoseconds directly.

Comment: For those of you, like me, wondering why `getSystemTime` returns a fancy data structure instead of, say, a [`Nano`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Fixed.html#t:Nano), the answer appears in the documentation: the `systemNanoseconds` field can be above 10^9 (during leap seconds)! This probably also explains why there is no pre-existing function that returns the time as a number of nanoseconds directly.